# How to use env var for API in NuxtJS axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, environment-variables, nuxt.js, dotenv

I have a working snippet

```
const response = await axios.get('http://example.com/categories')
```

But I want to refactor it by moving `http://example.com` to `.env`.

I made the following changes but successful

1. `.env` contains `http://example.com`
2. `const response = await axios.get('/categories')`
3. In `nuxt.config.js`:

```
       publicRuntimeConfig: {
        axios: {
          baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
        },
      },
```

**Result:** It's trying to access `http://localhost:3000/categories`

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @AmirhosseinShahbazi for his answer.

Besides his advice on fix, I have also changed `nuxt.config.js`

from

```
       publicRuntimeConfig: {
        axios: {
          baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
        },
      },
```

to

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
```

Comment: By the looks of what you shared, it's okay. You probably did a minor error somewhere. Do you have a public Github repo or a [repro]?

Comment: Hi @kissu. Thanks for you attention. Github repo https://github.com/tenzan/kaganat-nuxt

Comment: Is it not working on local env or in production btw?

Comment: It's not working on local env

Comment: Also, what if you try with a different name than `API_URL`?

Comment: Trying different names didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Nuxt's Axios module in the project.
There's no need to import Axios for using it. By importing it, you're using a new instance, not the one you've actually injected with `baseURL`.

Just replace `await axios.get` with `await this.$axios.get` and remove your import.

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      error: null,
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const response = await this.$axios.get('categories')
      this.categories = response.data
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error
    }
  },
}
</script>
```